# what is the mechanism of listeners in GUI Programming using Threads?

Tags: java, user-interface, listener, actionlistener

what is the mechanism of listeners in GUI Programming using Threads.  For example, are there any threads involved in ActionListener/actionPerformed method while a GUI runs?  What is the effect of these threads (if they do exist) on any user-defined Threads? Do they alter the behavior of user-defined threads?

Answer (score 2):

> what is the mechanism of listeners in GUI Programming using Threads. For example, are there any threads involved in ActionListener/actionPerformed method while a GUI runs?

For a straight forward ActionListener there is only one thread involved, the [Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) or EDT which is the main Swing event thread. This single thread is responsible for all Swing graphics and user interactions, and most Swing method calls need to be made on this thread (unless the API states that they are thread safe).

As for the rest of your question,

> What is the effect of these threads (if they do exist) on any user-defined Threads? Do they alter the behavior of user-defined threads?

I honestly have no idea what you're asking about. Other threads may be used in Swing GUI programs, and in fact there are situations where they are required, but when used, the coder must take care to make sure that most all Swing calls from these background threads are made on the Event thread.

Could you clarify just what it is that you are confused about or what is driving this question?

Comment: My question is that, as you just said, there is only one thread involved which is EDT.
Now, if I define my own thread, is there an effect on my thread b/c EDT? or they will just work perfectly beside each other?

Comment: @MohamedMagdyHassan: it will work the same as ***any*** two separate threads would work. There's nothing different here on how threading would work. Again, what instigated this question?

Comment: actually it is a homework question, and I search for it for weeks with out finding any answer!!

Comment: @MohamedMagdyHassan: Perhaps it's because the question, "how do two threads work together", is still very nebulous. If that was the exact question given you, then a demerit for the teacher because it is a terrible question.

Comment: From memory, on Winows, under Java 6, the EDT runs on a slightly higher priority to NORM. This may ave a slight effect in scheduling (who gets to run & when), but as HovercraftFullOfEels states, the EDT is just another thread, governed by the same rules as all Java Threads

Answer (score 2):

There is only one thread involved in the whole of Swing, and that is the Event Dispatch Thread. Swing, as many other GUI frameworks, is single-threaded.

Answer (score 2):

The only thread that should ever be involved with GUI listeners is the [Event Dispatching Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)

As to if they effect any set defined threads, the EDT won't, and unless you gave written your listeners to do otherwise, neither should the listeners